# How to update git repos automatically?

Tags: git

I have a work directory's: `D:\Dev\\replay`, `D:\Dev\\common` and `D:\Dev\\tools`

Usually I start my work day like this in `gitbash`:

```
cd d:\dev\\replay
git pull upstream develop
cd d:\dev\\common
git pull upstream develop
```

etc.

Instead of doing this I want to click on a script file and then get all three updated

How to write a script that do this for me (automatically)?

Comment: What do you mean "automatically" and why would you need that? Pulling periodically would require that `replay` is read-only (othewise you'd have conflicts) and could easily be a bare repo.

Comment: Tools like SourceTree actually do periodic *fetches* and warn you if there are changes. You can then apply the fetched changes to your local repos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using bash: in a file, e.g. "update-repositories"

```sh
prefix='d:/dev'
repositories=(replay common tools)
for repository in "${repositories[@]}"
do cd "$prefix/$repository" && git pull upstream develop
done
```

Execute as

```
bash update-repositories
```

Sidenote:
Can't judge without knowing the specifics, but this workflow feels a little odd. If you really must work on multiple repositories at once, then they're intrinsically associated you should probably track these associations too (e.g. which version of a tree works with which version of the others). [git submodules](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) allow you to do this, and they provide the expected commands to e.g. update all submodules (which are just normal repositories) to the latest version of an arbitrary branch. All you'd need is add a fourth repository with the others as submodules.

Comment: Where can I execute it? in the gitbash?

Comment: @Anatoly I'd say from anywhere depending on how program execution works "anywhere". In a bash session "bash" will be in your path so if the "update-repositories" script is in the current working directory it will work as I've shown typing "bash update-repositories". If you create an icon shortcut on your desktop or start menu, you'll probably have to specify bash.exe's path and the script's path in full.

Comment: I created file in the notepad `update-repositories` and copy it to the disk `d`. Then I go to my `gitbash` and type: `cd d:` and `bash update-repositories` I get `bash: update-repositories: No such file or directory`

Comment: First-off, you're lucky you mentioned using notepad; it's a notorious issue as it writes CRLF newlines where bash expects LFs only for its scripts. I suggest you use a "proper" editor for this. In any case, this isn't your immediate issue; after `cd d:`, type `pwd` and `ls` to print the working directory name and a listing of its files. Can you figure out where you are? (Note that I've tried the `d:` path syntax on Cygwin only, but I'd imagine it works fine with the git-for-windows SDK, also you seemed to use it yourself).

Comment: @Anatoly Oh, I think I might have it: notepad automatically adds a `.txt` extension, doesn't it?